# representation of numbers in bash and printf of hexadecimal numbers in bash

Tags: bash, double, printf, hex

I want to understand how numbers (doubles) are represented in bash and what happens when I printf numbers in hexadecimal format in bash.

According to the IEEE 754 standard double should be represented by 64 bits: 52 bits (13 hex numbers) for a significand, 11 bits for the exponent and 1 bit for sign.

To check it, I wrote a simple C program that transforms hex into dec (using printf).

```
include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("hex read = %40.24a\n", 0x1.000010C6F7A0B5E1Fp+0);
}
```

compiling with gcc 4.2.1, I get

```
hex read =          0x1.000010c6f7a0b00000000000p+0
```

From this result I conclude, that as I expect significand is defined by 13 hex digits 000010c6f7a0b.

Now I turn to bash and use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hex read = 0x"$1
printf "hex       =%80.70a\n" "0x"$1
printf "hex -> dec=%80.70f\n" `echo "0x"$1`
```

**GNU bash 3.2.48**

```
$ bash hex2dec 1.000010C6F7A0B5E1F
hex read = 0x1.000010C6F7A0B5E1F
hex       =   0x1.000010c6f7a0b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000p+0
hex -> dec=        1.0000009999999999177333620536956004798412322998046875000000000000000000
```

So everything worked as I expected: 13 hex digits define the significand of the number.

**GNU bash 4.1.5**

```
$ bash hex2dec 1.000010C6F7A0B5E1F
hex read = 0x1.000010C6F7A0B5E1F
hex       =   0x8.00008637bd05af10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000p-3
hex -> dec=        1.0000009999999999993737856418540843606024282053112983703613281250000000
```

This is not what I expected!

**Question 1** Why in GNU bash 4.1.5 double's significand is represented by 16 hex digits (instead of 13 according to IEEE 754)?

**Question 2** Why printf "%a" represents the hex number in a different format in different bash versions (**bash 3.2.48** 0x1.hh...hp+d and **bash 4.1.5** 0xh.hh...hp+d?). Shouldn't printf follow the same standard in both bash versions and be reglamented by http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html?

Comment: If there was a change it was most likely a bugfix (or regression). Those are both old versions. Check the changelogs. Bash has been around longer than C99 and therefore I would assume also `%a` and hex floating point literals. Note POSIX doesn't require `printf(1)` to support any of the floating point format specifications, so all of these things go beyond the minimum requirement for `printf(1)`. `%a` is probably one of the least portable of those.

Comment: @ormaaj, thank you for the comment. I didn't find info on how to check changelogs on http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html Could you, please, provide a link? I also didn't find the official website that contains reglamentation for printf(1). I thought it should be available at opengroup.org, but I found only printf (not printf(1)) specification. Printf specification includes %a though. So, could you, please, also provide me with a link to the official page that describes printf(1) format? Finally, how to understand which standard follows this particular version of bash? Thank you!

Comment: [printf utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94) [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=devel) FWIW, I got results that agree with the older bash behaviour in ksh93.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1** The current bash's [printf](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/printf.def) on x86 uses `long double` for input/output conversion in accordance with IEEE 754 (cf. [Extended and extendable precision formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Extended_and_extendable_precision_formats), [x86 Extended Precision Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format) and bash's printf's definition of [floatmax_t](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/printf.def#n200)), similar to the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%La\n", strtold("0x1.000010C6F7A0B5E1F", NULL));
}
```

- its output is `0x8.00008637bd05af1p-3`.

**Answer 2** Bash ultimately uses the C library's `printf`; the output of the C program above does follow the standard you refer to:

> there is one hexadecimal digit (which shall be **non-zero** if the argument is a normalized floating-point number and is **otherwise unspecified**) before the decimal-point character